# Usar métodos de um projeto escrito em C++ em C# (Na mesma Solution)

Tags: c#, .net, c++, assembly

Olá,

Preciso consumir métodos escritos em C++ em um projeto escrito em C#, dentro do .NET (ambos) e que estão contidos na mesma solution (como mostra a imagem abaixo)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Tentei compilar os projetos e adicionar a referência do projeto C++ (que foi criado em modo DLL->Empty Project pelo visual studio), e quando adicionei (ao projeto C#) não ficou disponível para eu usar a classe que eu estou desenvolvendo em C++

Então removi a referência e tentei adicionar novamente (pois havia ficado com um triângulo amarelo em cima), e agora quando tento carregar a referencia, mostra a seguinte mensagem de erro:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Preciso disso pois tenho que implementar um método em linguagem assembly, e o C# não me permite programar assembly como o C++ permite (*é um trabalho para faculdade, e não queria escrever o programa todo em C++ e sim em C#, o ponto é só o assembly mesmo)

Comment: Você precisa sair do código gerenciado para o não gerenciado; é chato, mas é isso que precisa ser feito

Comment: Já tentou seguir estas dicas do MSDN? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms235282.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nas propriedades do seu projeto C++ altere a opção  "Common Language Runtime Support" para "Common Language Runtime Support (/clr)" em "Configuration Properties->General->Project Defaults". Bibliotecas desenvolvidas sem CLR não podem ser referenciadas diretamente no C#, por isso você deve criar sua biblioteca em C++ usando a CLR.